# MySQL - query condition, which only triggers if another query condition returns no results

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it possible in MySQL, to add a WHERE condition, only if a preceeding where condition would return no results, without firing two consecutive queries?

So, basically what I am looking for is:

Consider the following table: `Currencies`:

```
| CurrencyId | CurrencyCode | CurrencyName         |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | EUR          | Euro                 |
| 2          | USD          | United States Dollar |
| 3          | GBP          | Great Brittain Pond  |
| 4          | RON          | Romanian New Lei     |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Currencies WHERE (CurrencyCode LIKE '%RO%' OR CurrencyName LIKE '%RO%') AND CurrencyId <= 4
```

This query will return row 1 (Euro contains 'ro'), and row 4 (RON contains 'RO'). What I would like to achieve, is to write a query, which first runs only the first LIKE statement, if there are results, it ignores the second LIKE statement, otherwise, it tries the second LIKE statements. In both cases the query should run the other conditions. So basically, the above query, if rewritten, should only return row number 4.

Is this possible somehow in MySQL?

Comment: .. `WHERE (NOT X AND Y) OR X` ?

Comment: @Alma, still it will return 1 & 4 row in output.

Comment: @Adam, you can't do it in single query you have to write group of statement for that.

Comment: Is this a correct phrasing?  "I want _all_ the rows with `CurrencyCode LIKE '%RO%'`, but if there are none, then _all_ the rows with `CurrencyName LIKE '%RO%'`.  And I don't care what order they are in otherwise."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get both rows, then pick the preferred one:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ( ... LIKE ... OR ... LIKE ... )
      AND ...
    ORDER BY CurrencyCode LIKE '%RO%' DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

`LIKE` returns true/false, which can be treated as 1/0, hence the `DESC`.

If there are multiple matching codes, they will be returned first, but in no particular order.

If you want to give preference to rows where the Code *and* Name match, then

```
    ORDER BY CurrencyCode LIKE '%RO%' DESC,
             CurrencyName LIKE '%RO%' DESC
```

(See also `CASE ...` for variations on this.)

**Modified**

Based on new specification...

```
( SELECT ... WHERE CurrencyCode LIKE ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE CurrencyName LIKE ...
               AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                        WHERE CurrencyCode LIKE ... ) )
```

The first `SELECT` will get all the matching Codes, if any.
The second `SELECT` will fail if there are any matching Codes, otherwise will deliver matching Names.

You could add `ORDER BY` in each `SELECT` or at the very end.

Comment: This won't work in cases I have multiple rows needed to be returned, because multiple CurrencyCodes match the desired result:(